# NHibernate DTO mapping

Tags: nhibernate, mapping

1. Is it OK to create Mappings for DTO objects and then query them
   instead of domain? If it is not explain why?
2. What If i need couple of those dtos?

---

- DTos are readonly
- ID is autogenerated by NH
- In future these dtos will have set mappings to linked dtos.
- I use DTO to reduce query size

  ```
  <class name="Person" table="`APP_Person`">  
      <property name="FirstName" type="string" length="512" />
      <property name="Age" type="int" /> 
      <property name="SocialNumber" type="int" />
      <property name="PassportId" type="int" />
      <property name="Salary" type="int" />
  </class>

  <class  name="PersonDTO" table="`APP_Person`">  
      <property name="FirstName" type="string" length="512" />
      <property name="Age" type="int" />
  </class>
  ```

Comment: Quite a few questions 1) Are these READ only DTO's and 2) will you ever try to map collections or many-to-ones here as well? 3) where is your ID stategy? Is this a attempt to optimise the data returned?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to map/persist a `DTO` object. It's normaly to readonly data and send to other layer of your application (web services, views, etc...).

You can create a query on the `Person` entity that returns a `PersonDTO` list. Take a look at `SetResultTransformer` method. Try somethin like this:

```
var query = session.CreateQuery("select p.FirstName, p.Age from Person p order by p.FirstName")
                   .SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(PersonDTO)))
                   .List<PersonDTO>();
```

And your DTO:

```
public class PersonDTO 
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The result of the column on the `hql` query should have the same name of your DTO's properties to NHibernate do the right reflection when construct the DTO and hydrate the object.

### Linq

You also can use `linq` to have a `DTO` (or a list of DTOs) as a result. For sample:

```
var query = Session.Query<Person>().OrderBy(x => x.FirstName)
                   .Select(x = new PersonDTO() { FirstName = x.FirstName, Age = x.Age })
                   .ToList();
```

Look this article: http://gustavoringel.blogspot.com.br/2009/02/creating-dto-in-nhibernate-hql-using.html

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong: We do not use dtos mappings because it should be in different application layer.

Comment: DTO (Data Transfer Object), it is only for transfer information from your data access layer to other layer like View or share it by a Web Service. when you use an ORM tool, it is a good pratice, because nHibernate has a proxy that allow the ORm to contrl your entities. With a DTO you don't have this infra-structure. Look this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: +1 for that PS note. Makes me wonder if there's a way to override the reflection to assign columns to properties.